# What's the equivalent of component in vue to angular?

Tags: angular, vue.js

How to render in dynamic component in Angular in the easy way that vue does?

In vue for example, to render dynamic component I write:

```
<component v-bind:is="'componentX'"></component>
```

What's the equivalent in angular?

Comment: In angular your gonna need to use factory to render dynamic component.

Comment: This defiantly needs to be easier now that Angular 12 is here, but it still is not.

Answer (score 1):

From the **[docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)**

The **`<ng-template>`** element is where you apply the directive you just made. To apply the AdDirective, recall the selector from ad.directive.ts, ad-host.

Apply that to  without the square brackets. Now Angular knows where to dynamically load components.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's much more complex than vue.

- First you have to prepare all `TemplateRef`s in your class, which means you have to know them beforehand.
- Also, after initializing the template ref value, you need to call `detectChanges()` to update the component.
- Then, in your html file, you need to prepare all `<ng-template>`'s and then add the `<ng-content>` tag to set the template ref that you want.
- There's a lot of code duplication here, but it works.

Important: Make sure `strict` is set to `false` in `tsconfig.json`, otherwise Angular will complain about a million things.

```js
// example.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html'
})

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('foo') foo: TemplateRef<any>
  @ViewChild('bar') bar: TemplateRef<any>
  comp: string

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.comp = 'bar'
    this.cdr.detectChanges()
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- example.component.html -->

<ng-template #foo>
  <foo></foo>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #bar>
  <bar></bar>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="this[this.comp]"></ng-container>
```